# Saving URL of image in microsoft nopcommerce database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nopcommerce, imageurl

I want to save a image URL in nopcommerce database. Could anybody give me an idea how could I save the URL of the image in NOPCOMMERCE database? 
This GetThumbUrl method is for getting image url and InsertPicture method is for inserting image without image path in database.

How to call the method GetThumbUrl in InsertPicture method for saving image path in database?

```
public string GetThumbUrl(string thumbFileName, string storeLocation = null)
        {
            storeLocation = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(storeLocation)
                                    ? storeLocation
                                    : _webHelper.GetStoreLocation();
            var url = storeLocation + "content/images/thumbs/";

            if (_mediaSettings.MultipleThumbDirectories)
            {
                //get the first two letters of the file name
                var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(thumbFileName);
                if (fileNameWithoutExtension != null && fileNameWithoutExtension.Length > MULTIPLE_THUMB_DIRECTORIES_LENGTH)
                {
                    var subDirectoryName = fileNameWithoutExtension.Substring(0, MULTIPLE_THUMB_DIRECTORIES_LENGTH);
                    url = url + subDirectoryName + "/";
                }
            }

            url = url + thumbFileName;
            return url;
        }



    public virtual Picture InsertPicture(byte[] pictureBinary, string mimeType, string seoFilename,
        string altAttribute = null, string titleAttribute = null,
        bool isNew = true, bool validateBinary = true)
    {

        int targetSize = 0;
        PictureType defaultPictureType = PictureType.Entity;
        string storeLocation = null;

        mimeType = CommonHelper.EnsureNotNull(mimeType);
        mimeType = CommonHelper.EnsureMaximumLength(mimeType, 20);

        seoFilename = CommonHelper.EnsureMaximumLength(seoFilename, 100);

        if (validateBinary)
            pictureBinary = ValidatePicture(pictureBinary, mimeType);


        var inspicture = new Picture
        {
            PictureBinary = this.StoreInDb ? pictureBinary : new byte[0],
            MimeType = mimeType,
            SeoFilename = seoFilename,
            AltAttribute = altAttribute,
            TitleAttribute = titleAttribute,
            IsNew = isNew,
        };
        _pictureRepository.Insert(inspicture);

        if (!this.StoreInDb)
            SavePictureInFile(inspicture.Id, pictureBinary, mimeType);

        //event notification
        _eventPublisher.EntityInserted(inspicture);

        return inspicture;
    }
```

Comment: are you mean you want to download an image from Url and save it your database ? or you just want to upload an image to your server and keep this image path in your database?

Comment: I want to save the image path to the nopcommerce database. Is there any way to do so?